# Why can't my script fetch a Grapes dependency?

Tags: groovy, apache-commons-io

I have a script with a Grapes dependency, shown below:

```
@Grapes(@Grab(group="commons-io", module="commons-io", version="2.4"))
import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream
...
```

But when I run it, I'm getting an error that the dependency can't be found.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: commons-io#commons-io;2.4: not found]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: commons-io#commons-io;2.4: not found]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
...
```

I'm using Groovy 2.0.5 with Java 1.6.0_33.

I checked Maven central and [the dependency does exist](https://search.maven.org/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/jar). Why can't Grapes find it?

Comment: I think it's a safe bet to assume, that your ancient java version can not talk to any recent https endpoint.

Comment: Looks like grapes was defaulting to a codehaus server which no longer exists. Updating the Groovy version solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These two ways work for me in Eclipse, but not in Netbeans. Whichever way you use, your `group` should be `org.apache.commons`

```
groovy.grape.Grape.grab(group:'org.apache.commons', module:'commons-lang3', version:'3.3.2')
```

or:

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-lang3', version='3.3.2')
```